# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: robotframework

i have set my path as below:

```
*** Keywords ***
Setup chromedriver
    Set Environment Variable    webdriver.chrome.driver    C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe
```

even though i am getting above mentioned error.

Comment: So what is unclear in this error text?

Comment: following keywords i am using for my test:*** Keywords ***
Open fastwire
    open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window

Enter department Id
    Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="Text2"]    ${department Id}

Enter userid
    Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="Text1"]    ${userid}

Enter Password
    Input Text    xpath=//*[@name="password"]    ${password}

Click Login
    Click Button    xpath=//*[@title="Logon"]

Check Title
    Title Should be    ${DashboardTitle}

Comment: @Dominic Can you please add the information to your question using the [edit] functionality? This includes a complete example, including test cases, library imports and custom keywords. In the question section you can post it in a formatted way, making it more readable.

Comment: Please don't show a picture of code. Take the time to create and format a proper [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Robot framework pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240047/chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-robot-framework-pycharm)

Answer (score -1):

"Open fastwire open" this keyword is not being read so u are getting error, go to settings-> map that resource file which has "open fastwire open" keyword with Login to fastwire open keyword

Comment: i Resolved it , now i am getting following this error could u please help me on this?  WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Comment: pls set path variable for chromedriver.exe file.Alternate option is setting path by code:  Set Environment Variable  webdriver.chrome.driver  ${EXECDIR}/chromedriver.exe
  Open Browser   https://amazon.in    gc

Comment: i have added and tried still i am facing same issue.

Comment: Sometime it doesn't take random path, then u can put chromedriver.exe file in C:\Python27\Scripts folder